# Как можно переместить разные блоки в список li

Tags: html, css

Имеется блоки,у которых разное айди,но они находятся в одном общем блоке.К примеру :

```
<div id="DIV-1">
    <div id="DIV-34"></div>
    <div id="DIV-56"></div>
    <div id="DIV-76"></div>
    <div id="DIV-98"></div>
</div>
```

Как можно быстро переместить каждый блок в li,например :

```
<li><div id="DIV-34"></div><li>
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит перенести? Вы же даже написали, как это делается.. Возьмите и оберните ваши `div` в тег `li`. Или в вопросе есть какой то тайный смысл с недосказанность? )

Comment: @SwaD я имею ввиду как БЫСТРО это сделать

Comment: Может на js получиться?Также у меня саблайм текст,может на нём какой плагин?

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать через замену... можно в JS код написать. Хотя за такое время уже можно было все поменять. Вопрос как раз был - вам это надо сделать по событию на сайте или просто поменять. У вас же там не тысячи дивов )

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался.С помощью функции find and replace в Sublime Text

Comment: Привел бы пример того что сделал... Тут можно было бы его запустить.